# Comma-Delimiter troubles in Dataverse Table export to Data Lake

Tags: azure, export-to-csv, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, dataverse

In Powerapps/Dataverse I can export tables to a Gen2 data link via Synapse Link:

[image: Dataverse Table Selection]

The data arrives happily in the Data lake in CSV format:

[image: Data Lake CSV Files]

However, I now find myself subject to the age-old problem of delimiting characters in data. In this instance, if there's a comma in the individual field data, then any mapping I have, say from a CopyData task, are corrupted.

This seems to be absolutely fundamental, and would break this Microsoft-prescribed pattern and solution for a large proportion of use-cases.

The process for files seems to be a bit of a black box, and I can't see a way of stipulating a custom delimiter as part of this.

Does anyone know how I might solve this?

Comment: If its possible to get data from dataverse into CSV where there is a specific quote character for the data say double quote as in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/jpKUFQD.png), then copy data will be able to infer the data correctly.

Comment: Yes, that might work, although, some of the fields are free-format (e.g. email messages). We can't guarantee there won't be quote characters there as well :-(.

Comment: If there are both single and double quotes present as a part of field value, then you can try to define your own quote character say `'''` (triple quote) and get the data from Dataverse (I am not aware if it is possible to do in Dataverse), then while creating the CSV dataset you can define your own quote character as in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/80rtJ42.png).

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the problem. I'm not sure the extent to which the dataverse can be configured. My guess is 'not at all'. Support call with Microsoft tomorrow, so lets see how that goes.